# 3g not showing up in network manager anymore

Tags: arch-linux, 3g, networkmanager

After I upgraded some packages, the 3g stopped showing up in network manager. The 3g-device is

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV

Which still shows up under lsusb and works under windows.
network manager is version 0.9.8.0

I'm running:

Linux arch 3.8.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 27 12:36:59 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How do I make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

systemctl enable ModemManager

makes it work.

Networkmanager, however, lists is as "not enabled" after it is connected.